# Can't read file written in a different machine with the same code

Tags: c++, linux, file, file-io

I have a neural network and I'm trying to train it in a remote VM running debian. After the training I save the weights in a txt file and I download the file to my PC (Ubuntu 14). The problem is that I can't read the weights file (it loads wrong values) even though I can read it in the remote machine using the same code. Here is my code:

For reading:

```
void CNN::LoadWeights(char *fileName) {

    int i, j, k, m;

    FILE *f;
    if((f = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) return;

    for ( i=1; i<CNNSize; i++ ) {
        for( j=0; j<CNNLayers[i].FMCount; j++ ) {

            fscanf(f, "%f ", &CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].bias);

            for(k=0; k<CNNLayers[i].prevLayer->FMCount; k++) {
                for(m=0; m < CNNLayers[i].KernelSize * CNNLayers[i].KernelSize; m++) {
                    fscanf(f, "%f ", &CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].kernel[k][m]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

For writing:

```
void CNN::SaveWeights(char *fileName) {

    int i, j, k, m;

    FILE *f;
    if((f = fopen(fileName, "w")) == NULL) return;

    for ( i=1; i<CNNSize; i++ ) {
        for( j=0; j<CNNLayers[i].FMCount; j++ ) {

            fprintf(f, "%f ", CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].bias);

            for(k=0; k<CNNLayers[i].prevLayer->FMCount; k++) {
                for(m=0; m < CNNLayers[i].KernelSize * CNNLayers[i].KernelSize; m++) {

                    fprintf(f, "%f ", CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].kernel[k][m]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: How do you transfer the file between the systems? If you look at the file on your system, does it look okay? If you look in a hex-editor, does it still look okay? Newline issues? Are the loop counters the same?

Comment: Why debuggers where invented. It would behoove you to check at least *one* of those `fscanf` results for success/failure rather than assuming they all work-as-intended.

Comment: how to you transfer the file from the Debian machine to the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Since your functions silently die whenever `fopen` fails, are you sure you actually loaded anything ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I download it using scp, it does look okay if I open it with gedit, I don't have new lines in the file and the loop counters are exactly the same. I'm running exactly the same code in both machines.

Comment: @Quentin I checked it and it loads the file (with wrong values).

Comment: Where does it go wrong? What are the expected values at every step of loading? What are the actual values? If the file is too large to write this down for each step, can you create an example that is small enough? (though since it works on the remote machine, you could generate both the expected and actual values and diff them).

Comment: This is where my ignorance on Linux shines: also, did you use the same g++ version for both machines? What about floating point precision between the two machines?

Comment: @BartvanNierop Yes I use the same g++ version. I believe the problem lies in the different floating point precision. How can I overcome it?

Comment: You could read in the float value as a simple string and then convert with atof.

Comment: floating point precision means `float` or `double`. If you're using the same code then you're also using the same precision.

Comment: Do you have different locales on both machines, one using a dot as decimal separator and the other using a comma?

Comment: What type is `CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].kernel[k][m]`? If it is `double`, the problem is caused by `scanf` and `printf` behaving differently when it comes to float format specifiers.

Comment: @Adam The same code alone is not enough. You also need the same compiler, compiler version, the same architecture and the same compiler flags (at the very least).

Comment: @BartvanNierop: Not at all. As long as the types are the same, and the format specifiers are correct and values are within the range of both systems, `printf` and `scanf` should produce the same value, even mixing machine architectures that have different floating point formats. We're reading text here, it's used specifically for the purpose of transferring data without knowing the bit representation.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Their type is double and I have tried it with a double format specifier ('%g') but still had problems.

Comment: @MatsPetersson The key word being _should_. I remember spending many hours figuring out why `45. + 55. == 100` resulted in `false` (the values may have been different from `45.0` and `55.0`, but they were whole numbers that should have summed to `100`).

Comment: @BartvanNierop: That is a COMPLETELY different problem, and that won't always work when everything is exactly identical, because of how floating point math works.

Comment: @pap-x the format specifier for `double` is `%lf`, "long float".

Answer (score 1):

Your read function should be

```
        fscanf(f, "%lf ", &CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].bias);

        for(k=0; k<CNNLayers[i].prevLayer->FMCount; k++) {
            for(m=0; m < CNNLayers[i].KernelSize * CNNLayers[i].KernelSize; m++) {
                fscanf(f, "%lf ", &CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].kernel[k][m]);
            }
        }
```

Note that format is `"%lf"`, not `"%f"`. In `printf`, values are automatically translated from `float` to `double` so `%f` works for both `float` and `double`, but in `fscanf`, `%f` means `float`, so your data is being read in the wrong format and most importantly stored as `float` into the pointer of a `double`. Using `%lf` will indicate to `fscanf` that you want to read it into a `double`.

If you add `-Wformat` to your compile line (or better yet `-Wall -Werror`) it should give you a warning/error along the lines of "fscanf argument 1 expects float, given double" and you should heed that warning and fix your code accordingly.

To ensure that your input is working correctly, use:

```
 void input_error()
 {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error reading input"); 
     exit();
 }

...

  if (fscanf(f, "%lf ", &CNNLayers[i].FeatureMaps[j].bias) != 1)
  {
      input_error();
  }
```

Edit2: You may want to remove the space in your format (in other words, `"%lf`"`instead of`"%lf "`, as my experience with spaces in`fscanf`formats is that they are "not doing what you want, most of the time", and`fscanf` will skip whitespaces as needed before the actual input, so you should get at least as good results without the space.

Comment: I have already tried to use "%g" (and "%lg") in scanf (which is a double specifier) with no success. Is "%lf" any different?

Comment: If that doesn't work, the problem is somewhere else, not in the code you are showing. Can you write a SIMPLE and standalone program that shows the problem. See also my edit on error checking above.

Comment: It doesn't print any error during the reading and also the removal of space doesn't improve the situation. I don't think the error lies anywhere else in the code because if I write and read the file in the same PC it works properly.

Comment: Then, like I said, the error is probably somewhere else. Checksum your file before and after copying as a first step, to make sure that the file hasn't gone wrong. Show us a complete example (probably in a new question) of code that writes a small set of data to a file, and then reads the same file, along with the actual file.